# date picker npm doesn't work in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

> I'm trying to make a date picker app using 
>   [react-native-modal-datetime-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) I'm using a button to open the
>   time picker but it doesn't pop up as I expected

**This is my constructor props**

```
constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         cdate: '',
         setDate: '',
         isVisible: false,
         setVisible: false,

      }
```

**Inside render**

```
render() {

  const { cdate, isVisible, setDate, setVisible } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.gridContainer}>

              <Text>{cdate}</Text>
      <Button title="Show DatePicker" onPress={() => this.setState({ setVisible: true })} />
             <DateTimePicker
  mode="time"
  isVisible={isVisible}
  cdate={cdate}
  onConfirm={cdate => {
    setDate(cdate.toTimeString());
    setVisible(false);
  }}
  onCancel={() => this.setState({ setVisible: false })}
/>
            </View>
    );
  }
}
```

> The app builds without any errors with the show date picker button but
>   when I press the button  it doesn't show the time picker as it should

[image]

I don't get the clock in the above picture when I press the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<DateTimePicker />` you have written `isVisible={isVisible}` but in

```
Button title="Show DatePicker" onPress={() => this.setState({ setVisible: true })}   ,
```

you are setting setVisible to true, so in dateTime picker you should replace  your code with below snippet , isVisible with setVisible  is being replaced

```
     < DateTimePicker
  mode="time"
  isVisible={setVisible}
  cdate={cdate}
  onConfirm={cdate => {
    this.setState({setDate:cdate.toTimeString(),setVisible:false})
  }}
  onCancel={() => this.setState({ setVisible: false })}
/>
```

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: when I select time I get the error setDate is not a function. (In 'setDate(cdate.toTimeString())', 'setDate' is "")
can you help me

Comment: @Venda i've edited the answer, hope it helps you.  do upvote and accept if it was helpful. otherwise ask any doubts.

Comment: @Gautav Roy thank you  do much for helping me. Sorry for taking so long to accept the answer now only I checked the inbox once again thank you so much Gautav Roy

Comment: glad it helped :D